# limit exists meaning limitsup=limitinf in extended R

Tags: real-analysis, limits

There is a problem,I dont konw how to prove in one direction.
Claim: $\lim\limits_{x \to p}f(x)$ exists in the extended sense$\Leftrightarrow$ $\varlimsup_{x \to p}f(x)=\varliminf_{x \to p}f(x)$.
My question:I am stuck in $\Rightarrow$ in the case $\lim\limits_{x \to p}f(x)=+\infty \quad or-\infty$.
My try:if $\lim\limits_{x \to p}f(x)=+\infty$,E is the domain of f,it implies:$\forall G \gt0,\forall \delta \gt0,\exists x\in B_{\delta}(p) \cap E,s.t \quad f(x)\gt G$.Thus $\quad\forall \delta \gt 0,s(\delta)=\sup{\{f(x):x \in B_{\delta}(p) \cap E}\}\ge G,\varlimsup_{x \to p}f(x)= \lim\limits_{\delta \to 0^{+}}\ s(\delta)\ge G$,Let $G \to \infty$ we get$\quad \varlimsup_{x \to p}f(x)=\infty.$Now I dont know how to prove$\varliminf_{x \to p}f(x)=\infty$,Could you give me some hints?or $\quad$complete proof

Comment: When you wrote $\{\sup f(x):x\in B_\delta(P)\cap E\}$, did you mean to write $\sup\{f(x):x\in B_\delta(p)\cap E\}$?

Comment: yes,I have corrected it,thank you

Comment: No entirely. You are still using $P$ instead of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=\infty$. What this means is that, for each $M\in\Bbb R$, there is some $\eta>0$ such that $x\in B_\eta(p)\cap E\implies f(x)>M$. Assuming this, you want to prove that $\liminf_{x\to p}f(x)=\infty$, which means that $\lim_{\delta\to0}\inf\{f(x)\mid x\in B_\delta(p)\cap E\}=\infty$; in other words, you want to prove that, for each $M\in\Bbb R$, there is come $\delta_0>0$ such that $0<\delta<\delta_0\implies\inf\{f(x)\mid x\in B_\delta(p)\cap E\}>M$. Take $M'>M$ and take $\delta_0>0$ such that $x\in B_{\delta_0}(p)\cap E\implies f(x)>M'$. Then, if $0<\delta<\delta_0$,$$\inf\{f(x)\mid x\in B_\delta(p)\cap E\}\geqslant M'>M.$$

Comment: Thank you sir,I misunderstand the infinite limit at some point.

Comment: May be I should dig out the point P.